# Using query values in sub-query to get count data from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a parent/child/grandchild type table relationship defined as follows:

tableA:
parentID
description

tableB:
childID
parentId
description

tableC:
grandchildID
childId
description
itemComplete

I need to write a query that will list all records in tableB for any given parentID, along with the total count of grandchild records and the total count of grandchild records completed (where itemComplete = true).

the parentID will be part of the where clause (select * from tableB where parentId = x).  The problem I can't figure out is how to get the counts from tableC because the count is dependent on the current row value of the childId.

In other words, I need some sort of query that looks like:

```
select description,  
(select count (*) from tableC where childId = X) as Items,
(select count (*) from tableC where childId = X And itemComplete = true) as CompleteItems
from tableB where parentId=Y
```

Where X is the current row's childId from tableB.  How do I reference the childId from each row in my sub queries to get the number of items and number of items complete?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using subselects is one option but I prefer to `JOIN` both tables and use a `GROUP BY` clause using a `CASE`statement to get the totals.

```
SELECT b.description
       , COUNT(*) AS Items
       , SUM(CASE WHEN c.itemComplete = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CompleteItems
FROM   tableB b
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tableC c ON c.childid = b.childid
WHERE  b.parentID = 'Y'
GROUP BY
       b.description
```

If you insist on using your original statement, all that was missing was the reference to the outer table `tableB.childID`

```
select description,  
(select count (*) from tableC where childId = tableB.childID) as Items,
(select count (*) from tableC where childId = tableB.childID And itemComplete = true) as CompleteItems
from tableB where parentId=Y
```

or reformatted

```
SELECT description
       ,  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableC WHERE childId = tableB.childID) AS Items,
       ,  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableC WHERE childId = tableB.childID AND itemComplete = true) AS CompleteItems
FROM   tableB 
WHERE  parentId=Y
```

Comment: Thanks much!  Works perfectly.  +1 for the alternative, and better, suggestion with the Left Outer Join.

Comment: @Lieven, can you please explain why do you prefer to `JOIN` compare to the other method which was asked in the question?

Comment: Besides of not being a fan of correlated subqueries and depending on how intelligent the optimizer is: using a join should only require one table/index scan of tableC whereas the subquerie route requires two. As with all thing, compare plans to verify and don't take this as a blanket statement that subqueries always perform worse.

Comment: @CoderAbsolute Using correlated subqueries are well known as bad practice( also bad performance ) In most of the cases can be avoided .